# Control backstack when click on notification to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

the user click on the notification while app is in backgroud and the app is opened and jumped to PickUpActivity

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent picukUpIntent = new Intent(context, PickUpActivity.class);
picukUpIntent.putExtra(MainScreenActivity.ORDER_ID, orderId);
picukUpIntent.putExtra(NOTI_TYPE, 3);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                   context,
                   notificationId,
                   picukUpIntent,
                   PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                );

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mini_logo)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
  .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
mNotifyMgr.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

When the user clicks on notification while app is in back groundd, it jumps to PickUpActivity as I expected. The problem is that when the user clicks up or back button, it exits the app. I want that it jumps to MainScreenActivity when the user clicks back or up button. That works fine when the user click on notification while app is in foregroud. So I dont want to override back and up button behavior in PickUpActivity.
Is there any way to set parent of PickUpActivity is MainScreenActivity
I do set parent in Manifest but it does not work

```
<activity
    android:name=".screen.rating.PickUpActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".screen.main.MainScreenActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".screen.main.MainScreenActivity" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `onBackPressed` in your notifiaction activity.

After putextra() in your notification activity start. "onCreat()".

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    boolean launchedFromNotif = false;

    if (extras.containsKey("EXTRA_LAUNCHED_BY_NOTIFICATION")) {
        launchedFromNotif = extras.getBoolean("EXTRA_LAUNCHED_BY_NOTIFICATION");
    }

    if (launchedFromNotif) {
        // Launched from notification, handle as special case
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you required identifying your app state when an application in background or foreground so using below method you can identify your application state.

```
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }
        return isInBackground;
    }
```

then after simply added below a line of code into your back press event

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(context)){
            //open your main screen activity MainScreenActivity.class
        }else{
            // what you want
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem because if the user can hit the up or back button, of course the app is in foreground. But I also need this code in my app and your code works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: it means you say to me user press back button when?

Comment: make one function and call at both places when user press home button or back button

Comment: User clicks on the notification -> Start activity -> press back button. Anyway  I do need your code and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: if answer helpful for you so can you please accept because make helpful for another one

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to start activity your main Activity on BackPressed of Notification Screen

Implement the below code in your PickUpActivity Screen.

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();


        Intent intent = new Intent(PickUpActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

}
```

Comment: I dont want to override BackPressed